# ErrorDocument not working with .htaccess file

Tags: apache-httpd

I am trying to use a .htaccess file to setup specific behaviors for one directory.

My .htaccess is as follows:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /var/www/secret/logging.php

AuthName "My Password Protected Site"
AuthUserFile /var/www/secret/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user

# Set REMOTE_USER env variable on 401 ErrorDocument
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /secret/
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^401$
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{ENV:REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER}]
```

However, when attempting to test this, the Apache default error page states a 404 was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. All permissions are correct, all filepaths are correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to add an entry like this

```
<Files /var/www/secret/logging.php>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Why? That wouldn't seem to solve my errordocument issue?

Comment: reading [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792356/htaccess-errordocument-vs-rewriterule) I'm wondering if the two methods does not conflict with each other. What happen if you try to comment out all the rewrite part?

Comment: I am trying to implement this: http://serverfault.com/questions/460765/log-invalid-login-attempts-htpasswd